# Show variations on a column externally filtering by another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
Table T:

    colA    |    colB     |    colDate
-----------------------------------------------
     A      |     5       |  2018-11-07 00:00:00
     A      |     7       |  2018-11-07 12:00:00
     A      |     7       |  2018-11-08 23:05:00
     A      |     7       |  2018-11-09 06:15:00
     A      |     7       |  2018-11-09 00:00:00
     B      |     25      |  2018-11-07 00:00:00
     B      |     27      |  2018-11-07 12:00:00
     B      |     27      |  2018-11-08 23:05:00
     B      |     27      |  2018-11-09 06:15:00
     B      |     27      |  2018-11-09 00:00:00
```

First, I need to list all the vain each variable whose name is stored on  colA and whose value is stored on colB.

To do this, I'm using partition windows, and specifically, given the fact that I'm running on Postgres, the LAG function.

```
select colA, colB, colDate from (
    select colA, colB, colDate,
        lag(colB) over (partition by colA order by colDate) prev_colB
    from T
    order by colA, colDate
) Tsmart
where
Tsmart.colB != Tsmart.prev_colB or Tsmart.prev_colB is null
```

that gives as result

```
    colA    |    colB     |    colDate
-----------------------------------------------
     A      |     5       |  2018-11-07 00:00:00
     A      |     7       |  2018-11-07 12:00:00
     B      |     25      |  2018-11-07 00:00:00
     B      |     27      |  2018-11-07 12:00:00
```

The problem is, externally from the creation of `Tsmart` I need to filter this table on `colDate`.

For example, I want only the variations happening from `2018-11-09` onwards.
I expect a table like

```
    colA    |    colB     |    colDate
-----------------------------------------------
     A      |     7       |  2018-11-09 06:15:00
     A      |     7       |  2018-11-09 00:00:00
     B      |     27      |  2018-11-09 06:15:00
     B      |     27      |  2018-11-09 00:00:00
```

but of course, if I do the same select as before, only adding the `colDate` filter on the external, I get an empty table.

```
select colA, colB, colDate from (
    select colA, colB, colDate,
        lag(colB) over (partition by colA order by colDate) prev_colB
    from T
    order by colA, colDate
) Tsmart
where
(Tsmart.colB != Tsmart.prev_colB or Tsmart.prev_colB is null)
and Tsmart.colDate > '2018-11-09 00:00:00'
```

Assuming I cannot move the filter on `colDate` inside `Tsmart`, is there a way to obtain what I want?

edit: better explained the question

Comment: Why would it not be possible to move the filter on colDate inside Tsmart? Or do you mean that it's not what you want because it changes the results?

Comment: the result is exactly what I want, just I cannot add it internally for technology limitations

Comment: Can you explain what technology limitations you have?

Comment: @johey the sql is built in pieces by code and configuration files

Comment: So you cannot modify Tsmart? Only adding conditions in the outer part?

Are you able to modify / remove the outer condition `where
Tsmart.colB != Tsmart.prev_colB or Tsmart.prev_colB is null`? If not I guess what you want is not possible if you must use that Tsmart...

Comment: @johey the problem is that any filter working on colDate is not preknown but comes from a user-made choice. I am able to modify the query whatsoever, the only limitation is that any filter on colDate cannot be hardcoded.

Comment: I had a hard time understanding what you are trying to do but I think I get it now... How to solve it though, LOL. :-)

Comment: Actually, maybe your solution is correct, but you are just missing parentheses around your OR conditions?
So `where
(Tsmart.colB != Tsmart.prev_colB or Tsmart.prev_colB is null)
and Tsmart.colDate > '2018-11-09 00:00:00'`

Comment: @johey you are right, in this post a parenthesis is missing. In my real SQL it is correctly present. Fixing the post, thanks

Comment: Don't you have to add `WHERE Tsmart.colDate > '2018-11-09 00:00:00'` in the inline query where you perform the `lag`?

Comment: @winkbrace if I could I would

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the solution. It is quite simple indeed, and it consists on adding the previous timestamp to the row, and then accept the row if the previous value differs from the current, if the previous is null or if the previous timestamp does not match the date filter.

In practice:

```
select colA, colB, colDate from (
    select colA, colB, colDate
        lag(colB) over (partition by colA order by colDate) prev_colB,
        lag(colDate) over (partition by colA order by colDate) prev_colDate,
    from T
    order by colA, colDate
) Tsmart
where
    (Tsmart.colB != Tsmart.prev_colB or Tsmart.prev_colB is null
        or Tsmart.prev_colDate < '2018-11-09 00:00:00')
and Tsmart.colDate > '2018-11-09 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

Doesn't a simple aggregation do what you want?

```
select colA, colB, min(coldate)
from t
group by colA, colB;
```

You can then add the date condition either as a `where` or `having` condition -- depending on exactly what you intend (do you want "first date"s after the date; or do you want the first date that occurs after the date, even if there is one before).

I should add that if you actually want more columns, then you can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (colA, colB) t.*
from t
group by colA, colB, coldate;
```

Comment: nope, because colB could assume again a value it had assumed before, so you lose some variations

Comment: @balsick . . . I see *nothing* in your question about that.

Comment: if colB goes from 25 to 26 and then again to 25 and then to 25, and I want to show all variations, I would lose several data

Comment: you're right it was not properly specified in the question. fixed it, thanks